# Eclipse Kepler: create Web Service Wizard giving error on Axis webservice

Tags: eclipse, web-services, eclipse-plugin, apache-axis

I have already set the Axis bin directory path in Eclipse Kepler. When I try to create a axis2 webservice, I am getting following error.
[image]

Looking forward to hear from you soon.

Answer (score 0):

1. first make sure in Eclipse Preferences, under "Web Services" >
   "Axis2 Preferences", you need to browse to the folder, where you
   downloaded Axis2 Binaries (should be a folder with folders bin,
   conf, lib, repository, ... in it.). Below, you should get the message "Axis2 runtime loaded successfully" then.
2. Next you need to go to the Project Properties > "Project Facets" and
   check "Axis2 Web Services"